# Convert List<List<Object>> to Map<Object,List<Object>> Java8

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a Object

```
class Wrapper{ 
   private SomeObject someObject;
   private String value;
}

class SomeObject{
  private String id;
}
```

I have function that returns `List<List<Wrapper>>` I want to convert it to `Map<SomeObject,List<Wrapper>>`

At the moment I'm using looping and compare to to achieve this. Is there way to achieve this via Java8 streams

```
wrappers.stream()
            .flatMap(w -> w.stream()) //stream of wrapper
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(<not sure which mapping fucntion to use here>))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupingBy` collector along with the `flatMap` operator to get this done. Here's how it looks.

```
Map<SomeObject, List<Wrapper>> map = l.stream().flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Wrapper::getSomeObject));
```

However, an iterative version would be much readable and faster than streams.

```
Map<SomeObject, List<Wrapper>> m = new HashMap<>();
for (List<Wrapper> wrappers : l)
    for (Wrapper w : wrappers)
        m.computeIfAbsent(w.someObject, unused -> new ArrayList<Wrapper>()).add(w);
```